# WODM 7.5 Error when connecting to Decision Server - IO error when contacting "/res/j_security_check"

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

When trying to connect from Rule Studio/Decision Center to the Decision server on the sample server, I get below error.

IO error when contacting "/res/j_security_check"

using WAS 7 as sample server for the WODM Decision Server.

a. I am not using any certificates.
b. Rule Execution Server Management EAR is properly deployed and started.

Gone through the IBM documentation but it does not help much as the steps are already taken care of.
[IBM Documentation for resolution](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21495825)

Any faced this issue before and resolved ?

I have resolved the issue yesterday. The problem was I was providing the url as
[//localhost:9080/res]

The localhost is not getting resolved properly. I was working on VPN and after providing the IP address instead of the 'localhost', it worked fine.

Comment: Can you please post error stack trace?

Comment: I could not get a stack trace for this. It was just a message and could not find any logging. If you know there is logging for this somewhere, please post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue yesterday. The problem was I was providing the url as [//localhost:9080/res]

The localhost is not getting resolved properly. I was working on VPN and after providing the IP address instead of the 'localhost', it worked fine.